# Как добавить звук выстрела?

Tags: javascript

Есть js файл отвечающий за объекты в игре. в нем есть функция lastFire отвечающая за выстрел. Надо сделать так чтобы вместе с выстрелом воспроизводился звук выстрела.

```
lastFire: Date.now()
    speed: 8,
    collisionX: 0,
    collisionY: 0,
    collisionW: 0,
    collisionH: 0,
    replace: function (img, w, h, offsetX, offsetY, offsetW, offsetH) {
        if (this.nodes.length < 1) {
            this.nodes.push(new _drawImage(img, (width / 2) - 50, height - 110, w, h));
        }
        this.collisionX = this.nodes[0].x + offsetX;
        this.collisionY = this.nodes[0].y + offsetY;
        this.collisionW = offsetW;
        this.collisionH = offsetH;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто воспроизвести (без заморочки с HTML-элементами типа `<audio>` или JS Audio API), используй следующую конструкцию

```
let shotSound = new Audio('path/to/file.mp3');
shotSound.play();
```